# monotouch secure webservices

Tags: iphone, https, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, web-services

What are the steps involved in adding a secure webservice?

I can't seem to find a decent guide or anything anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monotouch only has support for BasicHttpBinding.  The WCF stuff hasn't been fully ported.  You can follow what the status of [Mono's WCF](http://www.mono-project.com/WCF) implementation is here.

Comment: |Hey

do you know how stable this is? last i heard it wasn't ready for prod

Comment: I've heard anecdotally that people have used WCF in apps that are currently in the app store and haven't had issues.  You might also want to check out the Service Stack project (http://www.servicestack.net/) as they've put together a web service framework.